# Convert an Object filled with Booleans into a String-Array Where Boolean is True

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say i have an object like this:

```
likedFoods:{
  pizza:true,
  pasta:false,
  steak:true,
  salad:false
}
```

And i want to filter out the falses and convert it into a string array like so:

```
compiledLikedFoods = ["pizza", "steak"]
```

What would be the best way to do it that isn't simply:

```
if (this.likedFoods.pizza == true) {this.compiledLikedFoods.push('pizza')};
if (this.likedFoods.pasta == true) {this.compiledLikedFoods.push('pasta')}'
if (this.likedFoods.steak == true) {this.compiledLikedFoods.push('steak')}'
if (this.likedFoods.salad == true) {this.compiledLikedFoods.push('salad')}'
```

(if there is one)

Thanks.

Comment: `Object.keys(likedFoods).filter(key => likedFoods[key] === true)`

Comment: @Andrey - **That's** what was nagging me. :-) That's cleaner than either of mine. I'd post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would filter object keys by its values

```
const likedFoods = {
  pizza:true,
  pasta:false,
  steak:true,
  salad:false
};
const compiledFood = Object.keys(likedFoods).filter(key => likedFoods[key] === true);
console.log(compiledFood); //["pizza", "steak"]
```

Comment: Genius! I thought about doing a filter but for some dumb reason i thought it only worked on arrays, and not objects - didn't consider '.keys' presents itself as an array.

Thanks, green-check coming your way as soon as the time restriction ends.

Comment: Side note: No need for `=== true` unless the OP has other truthy values in the object that they want to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a loop or `reduce` on the array returned by `Object.entries`:

Loop:

```
const compiledLikedFoods = [];
for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(likedFoods)) {
    if (value) {
        compiledLikedFoods.push(name);
    }
}
```

`reduce` (because any array op can be shoehorned into a `reduce`):

```
const compiledLikedFoods = Object.values(likedFoods).reduce((array, [name, value]) => {
    if (value) {
        array.push(name);
    }
    return array;
}, []);
```

But see [Andrey's much simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55046179/157247). *(Hangs head.)*

Comment: Note that yours is 1 loop through array, while keys + filter requires 2, so no head hanging needed, this one is potentially more performant (I didn't test it though)

Comment: @Andrey - Thanks. :-) But yours is no more loops than mine. Yours *does* require looking up each property' value on the object in the callback (whereas in mine, we already have the value), but looking up the value of a property on an object is *really, really fast*, so...

Comment: That's a good point @Andrey, its times like this i wish i could check more than one answer. Yours is great for the brevity, but if i had to push a bunch of objects into arrays i'd probably use T.J's

Comment: @Logan - :-) FWIW, I'd go with Andrey's solution if I had to do this in my code. (Well, I probably wouldn't use `=== true`, but that's a niggle.)

Answer (score 2):

You could just get tke keys and filter by value.

```js
var likedFoods = { pizza: true, pasta: false, steak: true, salad: false },
    compiledLikedFoods = Object.keys(likedFoods).filter(k => likedFoods[k]);

console.log(compiledLikedFoods);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop through the object and push the *key* to the array if *value* is `true`:

```js
var likedFoods={
  pizza:true,
  pasta:false,
  steak:true,
  salad:false
}
var compiledLikedFoods = [];
for(var o in likedFoods){
  if(likedFoods[o])
    compiledLikedFoods.push(o);
}
console.log(compiledLikedFoods)
```